# How to sell a product server-side via Stripe Elements

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a test product via https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/products. This product has an ID "prod_...". I would like to sell this product via Stripe Elements.

I have created a basic Stripe Elements form which takes the user's email address and their card information based on [their guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#creating-a-paymentintent):

`purchase.html`

```
    <form action="/api/process_payment" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email">
      <div id="card-element">
        <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
      </div>

      <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

      <button id="submit">Pay</button>
    </form>
```

`stripe.js`

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_lp7ZS0B23jNmorIoW6Wj0Rs2009E1xTCwS');
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form
var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#32325d",
  }
};

var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#card-element");

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: card,
    }
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      // The payment has been processed!
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
        // Show a success message to your customer
        // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback
        // execution. Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the
        // payment_intent.succeeded event that handles any business critical
        // post-payment actions.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However, the problem I have with this system is that I need to verify that the user's email address exists in my database. Therefore, I need to confirm the payment server-side rather than running stripe.confirmCardPayment(...).

I figured I could simply use flask to create a payment intent when they visit my purchase URL:

```
@app.route("/payment", methods=["GET"])
def payment():
    return render_template("payment.html)


@app.route("/api/process_payment", methods=["POST"])
def process_payment():
    data = request.get_json()
    if data["email"] ...:   # some check
        payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=2000,
            currency="gbp",
            payment_method_types=["card"],
        )
        stripe.PaymentIntent.confirm(payment_intent["id"],)
        # verify payment and give status to user
    else:
        # inform user of invalid email
```

So the idea would be that when the user submits the form, they POST the data to `/api/process_payment` which creates a payment intent based on that data and then processes the payment. However, I have not been able to work out a way of actually using their payment information within the payment intent. How can I process their payment server side?

Additionally, I would like to create a payment intent of one of my products rather than just specifying an amount. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create a PaymentIntent for a Product, or (at the moment) otherwise use Products server-side; you can only use them with [client-only Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client).

I think what you want do do here is use [this process](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent) which first creates the Payment Intent server-side (after your 'valid email check'), and then handles collecting payment details and handling any payment authentication bits client side.